# updating schema from a newly generated migration in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, database-schema

How do i do this? My original schema I had a table called "users" that had a bunch of records.  I deleted my original migration by accident and had to create a new one except the new one has a new additional record prior to the old one.

Sorry Im new to rails and databases specifically. Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you out.

### Some Database Terminology

- A **database** has **schemas**, **tables**, and **records** (upon other things).
- A **schema** is the structure of the database.  Things like table names, column names, and relationships.
- A **database** has **tables**.
- A **table** has **records**.
- A **record** is a row of data in a table.

### Migrations

A **migration** modifies the schema, or structure of the database, in some way.  For example, creating a new table or adding a column to a table.  Migrations are beneficial because you can keep track to the changes you make to the schema or even "undo" one.

### An Example

Let's say we already have a `users` table but we want to add a column called 'full_name' to it.  We can create a migration:

```
$ rails generate migration AddFullNameToUsers full_name:string
```

This will make a file in `db/migrate` called `<date>_add_full_name_to_users.rb` containing:

```
class AddFullNameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :full_name, :string
  end
end
```

However, no changes have been made to the database yet!  We need to execute the migration:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

Now our `users` table has a new column called `full_name`.  If we want to **undo** that we can `rollback` the migration:

```
$ rake db:rollback
```

Our user table no longer has a `full_name` column.

Comment: Sir, you have finally made me understand how to work with databases :) Cheers mate